# How to set a custom color for dialog buttons in MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, android-dialog, app-inventor, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to make a dialog box in the **MIT App Inventor**, in which we get a Dialog with a title (Choose mode), message (How do you want to get your location?) and two buttons ("Use GPS" and "Use IP or Search").

It's working fine in AI Companion app : [Screenshot of AI Companion app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfLaU.jpg)
[image]

It's working fine in Bluestacks : [Screenshot of Bluestacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Xdw.png)

But buttons are appearing white in a white background on my mobile (Android 9) : [Screenshot of the actual app in Android 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXMuB.jpg)
[image]

Please help me out with this.

Comment: You are using default Alert Dialog for presenting your Dialog view. in this way you are  somewhat limited to customizing your dialog layout. To obtain what are you seeking, you can use custom dialog extending Dialog with custom layout.

Comment: see here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/TdT4kAZO4bs/n-yBtPrACAAJ